# Split a string into array in Perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl, split

```
my $line = "file1.gz file2.gz file3.gz";
my @abc = split('', $line);
print "@abc\n";
```

Expected output:

```
file1.gz
file2.gz
file3.gz
```

I want the output to be `file1.gz` in `$abc[0]`, `file2.gz` in `$abc[1]`, and  `file3.gz` in `$abc[2]`. How do I split `$line`?

Comment: Well, no programming language can read your mind. `split ''` splits into individual characters. If all your filenames start with `file...`, then `split /(?=file)/` would work, but there is no general solution

Comment: @aragaer Your comment is factually wrong. [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) takes arguments as pattern, string, limit. Your order is wrong. And `print "@abc\n"` would work fine, provided that `$" eq "\n"` (`$"` is usually a space).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Splitting a string by whitespace is very simple:

```
print $_, "\n" for split ' ', 'file1.gz file1.gz file3.gz';
```

This is a special form of `split` actually (as this function usually takes patterns instead of strings):

> As another special case, `split` emulates the default behavior of the
>   command line tool `awk` when the `PATTERN` is either omitted or a literal
>   string composed of a single space character (such as `' '` or `"\x20"`). In this case, any leading whitespace in `EXPR` is
>   removed before splitting occurs, and the `PATTERN` is instead treated as
>   if it were `/\s+/`; in particular, this means that any contiguous
>   whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator.

---

Here's an answer for the original question (with a simple string without any whitespace):

Perhaps you want to split on `.gz` extension:

```
my $line = "file1.gzfile1.gzfile3.gz";
my @abc = split /(?<=\.gz)/, $line;
print $_, "\n" for @abc;
```

Here I used `(?<=...)` construct, which is [look-behind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions), basically making split at each point in the line preceded by `.gz` substring.

If you work with the fixed set of extensions, you can extend the pattern to include them all:

```
my $line = "file1.gzfile2.txtfile2.gzfile3.xls";
my @exts = ('txt', 'xls', 'gz');
my $patt = join '|', map { '(?<=\.' . $_ . ')' } @exts;
my @abc = split /$patt/, $line;
print $_, "\n" for @abc;
```

Comment: the question has been changed to include spaces

Comment: @user2384801 Added explanation and link.

Answer (score 14):

Having `$line` as it is now, you can simply split the string based on at least one whitespace separator

```
my @answer = split(' ', $line); # creates an @answer array
```

then

```
print("@answer\n");               # print array on one line
```

or

```
print("$_\n") for (@answer);      # print each element on one line
```

I prefer using `()` for `split`, `print` and `for`.

Comment: You should know that the default `' '` split is probably what you want instead of `/\s+/`. They are exactly the same, except the default strips leading whitespace before splitting.

Comment: @TLP Thanks a lot - have always used `/\s+/` ignoring that default `' '`. I still find `/\s+/` easier to understand as it does what it shows... But I guess `' '` is easy to remember, does exactly what one want (usually nobody cares having a 0-string as first element), and is certainly optimized to do it without the expensive use of a regex. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just use /\s+/ against '' as a splitter. In this case all "extra" blanks were removed. Usually this particular behaviour is required. So, in you case it will be:

```
my $line = "file1.gz file1.gz file3.gz";
my @abc = split(/\s+/, $line);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have multiple answers to your question, but I would like to add another minor one here that might help to add something.

To view data structures in Perl you can use [`Data::Dumper`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html). To print a string you can use [`say`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html), which adds a newline character `"\n"` after every call instead of adding it explicitly.

I usually use `\s` which matches a whitespace character. If you add `+` it matches one or more whitespace characters. You can read more about it here [`perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

use feature 'say';

my $line = "file1.gz file2.gz file3.gz";
my @abc  = split /\s+/, $line;

print Dumper \@abc;
say for @abc;
```

Comment: Is there a reason that people are downgrade this answer? According to the official documentation from [Perl::doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

"_In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were /\s+/ ; in particular, this means that any contiguous whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator._"

Answer (score 0):

I found this one to be very simple!

```
my $line = "file1.gz file2.gz file3.gz";

my @abc =  ($line =~ /(\w+[.]\w+)/g);

print $abc[0],"\n";
print $abc[1],"\n";
print $abc[2],"\n";
```

output:

```
file1.gz 
file2.gz 
file3.gz
```

Here take a look at this tutorial to find more on [Perl regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) and scroll down to **More matching** section.