# perl --> printing characters in between the multiple metacharacters present in a single line

Tags: perl, substr

I am trying a script to find out the characters between the metacharacter "|". I tried to get the position of the first and the succeeding "|" metacharacter  and tried to print the string between those two positions. Below is the code I tried:

File : | A| B| Count| D| E|

Expected output : A B Count D E

```
if($line =~ /\|/) 
{
while ($line =~ m/\|/g) 
{
my $start_pos = $-[0]; 
my $end_pos = $+[0]; 
my $hit_pos = "$start_pos - $end_pos";
my $char = substr($line, $start_pos, $end_pos);
if($char =~/\w/){
  print "$char\n";
}
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string into array in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872340/split-a-string-into-array-in-perl)

Comment: @tripleee, Not quite,

Comment: substr takes a length, not an end position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split`:

```
my $line = '| A| B| Count| D| E|';

my @fields = split(/\|/, $line, -1);
shift(@fields);  # Ignore stuff before first "|"
pop(@fields);    # Ignore stuff after last "|"

say "<$_>" for @fields;
```

Output:

```
< A>
< B>
< Count>
< D>
< E>
```

---

Using a regex match:

```
my $line = '| A| B| Count| D| E|';

my @fields = $line =~ / \| ([^|]*) (?=\|) /xg;

say "<$_>" for @fields;
```

Output:

```
< A>
< B>
< Count>
< D>
< E>
```

---

Using a regex match (alternative):

```
my $line = '| A| B| Count| D| E|';

while ($line =~ / \| ([^|]*) (?=\|) /xg) {
   say "<$1>";
}
```

Output:

```
< A>
< B>
< Count>
< D>
< E>
```

Comment: I want get the position of the "|" character and then separate the characters and store them in an array based on the position. something like @store[$pos] . Can you tell me a way to do that?

Comment: That's what the first snippet does `$fields[0]` contains `␠A`, `$fields[1]` contains `␠B`, etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a match-based solution that populates an array.

Comment: maybe `@fields = grep /w/, split /\|/, $line` is what's wanted? unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to just delete the pipes.

```
$line =~ s/\Q|\E//g;
```